# single quotes appear arround value after running copy in postgres 9.2

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am new to postgres and I play around with data loading.
Here is the table definition from postgres 9.2 spec:

```
CREATE TABLE weather (
    city varchar(80),
    temp_lo int, -- low temperature
    temp_hi int, -- high temperature
    prcp real, -- precipitation
    date date
 );
```

I prepared the following data file (weather.txt):

```
San Francisco   43  57  0.0 '1994-11-29'
Hayward 54  37  0.0 '1994-11-29'
```

and ran the COPY command:

```
COPY weather FROM '~aviad/postsgres/playground/weather.txt';
```

now, when I run `select * from weather;` I see that single quotes appears around the city values.
This does not happen when I run simple `INSERT` e.g:

```
INSERT INTO weather VALUES ('San Francisco', 46, 50, 0.25, '1994-11-27');
```

I wonder:

1. what is the reason for wrapping text values by single quotes?
2. What is the correct way to put the text data in the file used by
   `COPY` to avoid single quote wrapping?

Comment: I don't believe you, I'm afraid. I tried your table definition and sample data and saw no such quoting. There's something you've missed in your description. Oh - you don't need quotes around the dates by the way.

Comment: I don't see the quoting either. Anyway, when using `COPY`, I always append `WITH CSV HEADER` to use the standard CSV format. This has the added benefit such that the data file can be prepared / examined using Microsoft Excel or LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe in your question is obviously not what's really happening. `COPY` would fail trying to import string literals with redundant single quotes into a `date` column.

To get rid of redundant quotes, import to a [temporary table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html) with `text` column, then `INSERT INTO` the target table trimming the quotes:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE wtmp (
   city text
 , temp_lo int
 , temp_hi int
 , prcp real
 , date text  -- note how I use text here.
);

COPY wtmp FROM '~aviad/postsgres/playground/weather.txt';

INSERT INTO weather (city, temp_lo, temp_hi, prcp, date)
SELECT city, temp_lo, temp_hi, prcp, trim(date, '''')::date
FROM   wtmp
-- ORDER BY ?
;
```

The temp table is dropped automatically at the end of your session.

#### Reserved words as identifiers

I see you copied the example from the manual. Here is the [deep link to the current manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-table.html).

While being correct, that example in the manual is unfortunate. I'd advise not to use [reserved words like `date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as column names. As you can see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) `date` is a reserved word in every SQL standard. It's allowed to use in Postgres and I can see how it's tempting for a simple example. But that doesn't make it a good idea. Generally, you should be in the habit of *avoiding* reserved words as identifiers. It leads to confusing error messages and needlessly incompatible SQL code.

Comment: thanks, I was just trying to run the example from POstgres 9.2 spec, so, all the names appear as defined in Chapter 2 of the http://www.postgresql.org/files/documentation/pdf/9.2/postgresql-9.2-A4.pdf

Comment: @aviad: I see. Added a paragraph to my answer about that.

Answer (score 0):

1 - The practice of wrapping text in quoted identifiers is done in the event that the demiliter used within the file (comma in your case) also appears within the text string

2 - I do not know must about postgres, but if you specifiy the quoted identifier in your COPY command, it should remove it during the import:

```
COPY weather FROM '~aviad/postsgres/playground/weather.txt' (QUOTE '?');
```

something along those lines. Simply try replacing the ? with the quoted identifier - in your case, I would try this first:

```
COPY weather FROM '~aviad/postsgres/playground/weather.txt' (QUOTE '''');
```

You also might want to check out: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html as there are many different switches you can use in the COPY command

Comment: got 'COPY quote available only in CSV mode' I am loading from txt file with default delimiters (tab)

Comment: can you not treat the file as a CSV and then specify TAB as the demiliter ?

something along the lines of:

COPY weather FROM '~aviad/postsgres/playground/weather.txt' (DEMILITER '\t', QUOTE '''');